# How to access other properties of json object when clicked another item in my select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to access some other properties within JSON Objects (data).

Currently accessing the Icon & the name.

Here is the issue..

When selected an item in the `select` by doing this

```
$("#newLocation").change(function(e) {
    var select = e.target;
    alert(select.value);
});
```

It's accessing the value.

Instead of printing out the link which it does now, want to be able to access the object and print out other things like the `ACrush`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ymsq1uoy/88/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON.stringify()` when you set the attribute value and use `JSON.parse()` to get back the object. Then you can access whatever property of the object you want to access.

```
$.each(items, function (index) {
    $('#newLocation')
        .append($("<option></option>")
        .attr("value", JSON.stringify(items[index]))
        .text(items[index].Name));
});

$("#newLocation").change(function(e) {
    var select = e.target;
    alert(JSON.parse(select.value).ACrush);
});
```

Take a look at this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ymsq1uoy/93/

Comment: What if the `JSON` has a lot of attributes ? What if the `JSON` is dynamically changing . Storing the whole object in `<option>`'s value is not the ideal way .

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're separating your data and the DOM, so when you click something and read the value of what was clicked, you're just reading words off the page, you're not reading the data.

What you need to do is get what was clicked, then use that information to find the matching piece of data. Once you have the matching piece of data, you can do whatever you want with it.

Here's my Demo:

First: Add "id" properties to each item.

Second: Use said "id" to easily find that item and get it's information.

```
$("#newLocation").change(function(e) {
  // get id of what was clicked
  var selected_id = e.target.value; 

  // then use it to find right item`enter code here`
  var selected_item = items.find(function(item){
    return item.id === selected_id; 
  }); 

  // can now access any property
  alert(selected_item.MagicDamage); 
});
```

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vfcag6dy/2/)**

Comment: What about what @MdHasanIbrahim said? That seems to be what fits me the best

Comment: Don't get e wrong I really like yours too, seems as if it does the same thing without parsing

Comment: Using an "id" attribute is industry standard. It's less data for your app or website to have to parse. It's the most efficient. That's why items in grocery stores have IDs, and cars have VIN #'s (ids) and even people have social security numbers (ids). It's the best way to do it. Get the "id", look up the item by id.

Comment: @MarkDenom this is the right approach to do stuff like this. You should not put so much thing inside the DOM which may cause unnecessary performance issues. My answer was quite a quick fix that solved your need and the way you wanted. But I would suggest you to follow this approach.

Comment: For a small app, and for learning purposes, it really doesn't matter either way. But I'd argue the "id" approach is cleaner.

Comment: Ohhh! Okay thanks guys!
I am getting this error though https://i.imgur.com/uL5QRbU.png

Comment: Link your code. Make sure you are assigning your id to the value of the select item.

Comment: @TJBlackman https://jsfiddle.net/94c5ebav/3/ It won't pull any data since that web API is hosted on my PC locally just as a sidenote here is what the json looks like https://i.imgur.com/RHJqnZO.png

Comment: You said "Add ID's to each item" That makes sense but what should the ID be?

Comment: I wonder `jQuery` has `array.find()` function since you are looking for an answer in `jQuery` as in your tags.

Comment: The ID can be just a number. If this really isn't working for you, go with the JSON.Stringify option. Here's how I updated your code.
https://jsfiddle.net/k4xvparz/

Comment: Yeah it keeps saying `Cannot read property 'MagicDamage' of undefined` I get what you mean though and it makes sense

Comment: After debugging I think I found the issue, doesnt look like I am adding any items to the array :sigh:

Answer (score 0):

I updated your jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ymsq1uoy/91/ .

You could store the index of the item in `<option>`'s value and use it back when you change the `<select>` to reach the sub items , otherwise you may store the needed attribute in `<option>` and get it back `onChange` , something like `<option ACrush='..'` . The first approach is better though .

Comment: What about what @MdHasanIbrahim said? That seems to be what fits me the best

Comment: @MarkDenom Nope its not unfortunately ,  As he's storing the entire `JSON` object inside `<option value=` . What if the `JSON` object has a lot of attributes ? Ideally you refer to the object by its index not by repeating it !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.grep()` to filter your object and get any property from there,

```
var items =[];

$(document).ready(function(){
var data = {
    "ItemMode": [
      {
        "Icon": "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/2007scape/images/a/ad/Adamant_arrow_1.png/revision/latest?cb=20180212230525",
        "Name": "Adamant arrow",
        "AStab": "+0",
        "ASlash": "+0",
        "ACrush": "+0",
        "AMagic": "+0",
        "ARange": "+0",
        "DStab": "+0",
        "DSlash": "+0",
        "DCrush": "+0",
        "DMagic": "+0",
        "DRange": "+0",
        "MeleeStrength": "+0",
        "RangedStrength": "+31",
        "MagicDamage": "+0%",
        "Prayer": "+0",
        "Undead": "0",
        "Slayer": "0"
      },
      {
        "Icon": "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/2007scape/images/d/d5/Adamant_bolts_1.png/revision/latest?cb=20170914022209",
        "Name": "Adamant bolts",
        "AStab": "+0",
        "ASlash": "+0",
        "ACrush": "+0",
        "AMagic": "+0",
        "ARange": "+0",
        "DStab": "+0",
        "DSlash": "+0",
        "DCrush": "+0",
        "DMagic": "+0",
        "DRange": "+0",
        "MeleeStrength": "+0",
        "RangedStrength": "+100",
        "MagicDamage": "+0%",
        "Prayer": "+0",
        "Undead": "0",
        "Slayer": "0"
      }
]};
items = data.ItemMode;
$.each(items, function (index) {
    $('#newLocation')
        .append($("<option></option>")
        .attr("value", items[index].Name)
        .text(items[index].Name));
});
});


$("#newLocation").change(function() {
        var val =  $(this).val();
    var selectedItem =  $.grep(items, function(element, index){
         return element["Name"] == val; 
    });
    // You can get anyting 
    alert(selectedItem[0].ASlash);
    alert(selectedItem[0].Icon);
});
```

Check my fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8w1a65g4/6/)

Comment: This is literally the same as vanilla javascripts `Array.find()` lol

Comment: @TJBlackman May be. frameworks have own different ways to execute same functions.